# How do I update multiple items in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-bulk-api

Let's say I have a `tag` type in an ElasticSearch index, with the following mapping:

```
{
    "tag": {
        "properties": {
            "tag": {"type": "string", "store": "yes"},
            "aliases": {"type": "string"}
        }
    }
}
```

Each entry is a tag, and an array of aliases to that tag. Here is an example item:

```
{
    "word": "weak",
    "aliases": ["anemic", "anaemic", "faint", "flimsy"]
}
```

From time to time, I want to add new tag words with their aliases, and add new aliases to existing tag words.

Adding new tag words with their aliases is easy, it's just a new Document. However, how can I add new aliases to existing tag words in a sane way?

I know I can just search for the tag word, get its document, search to see if the alias already exists in the array of aliases, if not add it, than save. However - this does not sound like a good solution.

Is there a way to do a bulk update?

Answer (score 12):

Try this using [_bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/type/_bulk
{
"update": {
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "myid"
}
}{
"doc": {
    "field": "new value"
}
}{
"update": {
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "type",
    "_id": "id"
}
}{
"doc": {
    "field": "new value"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It's not need to specify `_index` and `_type` fields in every `update: {}` object, as it is already specified in request URL: `http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/type/_bulk`

Comment: To make this example working we need to write "object per line":
`{"update": {"_id": "myId0"}}
{"doc": {"field": "new value 0"}}
{"update": {"_id": "myId1}}
{"doc": {"field": "new value 1"}}
 
`
Also, make sure you have added `Content-Type: application/x-ndjson` header to the request.

Comment: @Varshaan: You have made my day!! Thanks Buddy!! :)

Answer (score 11):

All updates in ElasticSearch are done by finding the record, deleting the old version and adding the new version. You can save a little bit on moving records all the way to the client by using [Update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update.html). It would still require finding the record though.

What you, probably, want is [Update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/docs-update-by-query.html).

Comment: Update by query is still not added to Elastic, but a [plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/) exists.

Comment: As of Elasticsearch 2.3, update-by-query is available - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update-by-query.html

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

input_list.dat:

```
{ "index" : { "_index": "my_index", "_type": "my_type", "_id": "existing-value" } }

{ "Field_to_update": "New_Value" }

{ "index" : { "_index": "my_index", "_type": "my_type", "_id": "existing_value" } }

{ "Field_to_update": "New_Value" }
```

Command:

```
curl -k -XPOST 'https://my_host:9200/my_url/_bulk' --data-binary "@input_list.dat"; echo
```

Answer (score 4):

Elasticsearch 2.3.0 introduced the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-update-by-query.html) as part of the long awaited [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html).

As an example, here is how you could update all documents to delete a certain field if it exists:

```
POST /myindex/mytype/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"remove\")"
  },
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "remove"
    }
  }
}
```

The above example uses inline scripting, so be sure to enable it in `elasticsearch.yml` with `script.inline: on`.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Search has a [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html). With that API you can do the following:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/test/tag/weak/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.aliases += faint"
}'
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I implement update a single record in php?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ElasticSeach Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-update) for updating the multiple documents using a single API call

**CURL example**

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9200/whatsapp/_bulk' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{ "update" : {"_id" : 692, "_index" : "whatsapp","_type":"_doc","retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "doc" : {"thread_status" : 1} }
{ "update" : {"_id" : 693, "_index" : "whatsapp","_type":"_doc","retry_on_conflict" : 3} }
{ "doc" : {"thread_status" : 1} }

'
```

**NOTE** The final line of data must end with a newline character \n. That' why you will notice **'** at the end line of json.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you add same value with same id, it will automatically update older data.

Comment: Update or replace?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch's bulk APIs can be used for update requests as well, at least for the Java client.

```
List list = new Arraylist();
list.add("hello");
BulkProcessor bulk = new BulkProcessor();
UpdateRequest update = new UpdateRequest("index", "type", "id1");
update.script("ctx._source.aliases+= newaliases");  //dynamic script
update.addScriptParam("newaliases", list);
bulk.add(update);
```

Note that dynamic scripting is disabled in newer versions of elasticsearch. Either enable that or use pre-compiled scripts for using this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using spring java client using the following code. Following are the dependencies used in the code.

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.update.UpdateRequest;

import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQuery;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.UpdateQueryBuilder;

private UpdateQuery updateExistingDocument(String Id) {
    // Add updatedDateTime, CreatedDateTime, CreateBy, UpdatedBy field in existing documents in Elastic Search Engine
    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().doc("UpdatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedDateTime", new Date(), "CreatedBy", "admin", "UpdatedBy", "admin");

    // Create updateQuery
    UpdateQuery updateQuery = new UpdateQueryBuilder().withId(Id).withClass(ElasticSearchDocument.class).build();
    updateQuery.setUpdateRequest(updateRequest);

    // Execute update
     elasticsearchTemplate.update(updateQuery);
}
```